# iid random variables (vectors)

Tags: statistics, random-variables

If $(X_{1},Y_{1}), (X_{2}, Y_{2}),...,(X_{n}, Y_{n})$ denote a sequence of iid random variables from $(X,Y)$, can I say that each $X_{i}$ is independent from each $Y_{i}$?
Or is it just for the vector, i.e. that each $(X_{i},Y_{i})$ is independent from each $(X_{j},Y_{j})$ for $i \neq j$?

Comment: the latter. In fact, you can also say that $Y_i$ is independent of $Y_j$ for $i\neq j$, and $X_i$ is independent of $Y_j$ for $i\neq j$

Answer (score 2):

It is the latter interpretation that is valid.  It is not necessarily the case that $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are independent.  For example, $(X_i, Y_i)$ could be IID observations from a bivariate normal distribution with mean vector $\boldsymbol \mu$ and variance-covariance matrix $\boldsymbol \Sigma$.  But $X_i$ and $Y_i$, the marginals, are not independent univariate normal distributions unless the correlation is specifically stated to be $0$.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: A trivial example:  $X_i = Y_i \sim {\rm Normal}(0,1)$.  Then observations for each $i = 1, 2, \ldots$ are IID, but $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are obviously dependent.

Comment: now I see. thanks